# MySQL read explain - using where

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7, explain

In Oracle there is an important note in the explain plain where it says `filter a.col1=...` this one letting you know `col1` is first retrieved from the disk and only then filter is been done. This important piece of information let you know the exact column been used within a specific index and which are filter after and may be good candidate for index.

In MySQL explain result we see something like:

```
+----+-------------+-------+------------+--------+--------------------+---------+-------+--------+----------+------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | partitions | type   | key                | key_len | ref   | rows   | filtered | Extra                              |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+--------+--------------------+---------+-------+--------+----------+------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | SD    | NULL       | range  | ix_store_composite | 64      | NULL  | 252978 |    60.00 | Using index condition; Using where |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+--------+--------------------+---------+-------+--------+----------+------------------------------------+
```

What I would like to know which of the columns data are coming from the index and which are been filtered after (the `using where`).
I couldn't find any option to get additional detail on the explain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Using index condition" does not mean the same as "Using index".

Run this:

```
EXPLAIN FORMAT=JSON SELECT ...
```

If you need further help, post that in your Question.  Also show us the `SELECT`; it will help us go into more detail.

Comment: `FORMAT=JSON` is what I was looking for, thanks!